# Docker pull is not giving real time downloaded-size/total-size when executed through Node.js child process sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, exec, child-process

When I run `docker pull my-image` from my terminal this is how my output looks like.

```
 59e69571f6c7: Pull complete 
 43da27f69c98: Pull complete
 d22174e9eddd: Pull complete
 cc0ac48a6d21: Downloading 312.3 MB/2.888 GB
 b47aa969d5dc: Download complete
```

When I run a piece of Node.js code

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
 exec('docker pull my-image', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   if (error) {
     console.error('exec error: ${error}');
     return;
   }
   console.log('stdout: ${stdout}');
   console.log('stderr: ${stderr}');
 });
```

My output looks like this.

```
c49bda5ed612: Waiting
43da27f69c98: Verifying Checksum
43da27f69c98: Download complete
d22174e9eddd: Verifying Checksum
d22174e9eddd: Download complete
b47aa969d5dc: Verifying Checksum
```

I was expecting same output. Mainly the information regarding how much is downloaded and remaining. If I want to progress a progress bar based on the size of the image downloaded, there is no way to do with this output

Please let me know if there is a way to find real-time download size status.

FYI if you download any binary from curl, in Node.js exec command you get the real time bytes downloaded/total data.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: `312.3 MB/2.888 GB` This infirmation is not seen when executed in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

The output that you are mentioning only happens if the `docker` CLI is running somewhere where there is a pseudo-tty allocated. You can force the output to not have a pseudo-tty on the command line by running the command this way:

```
docker pull my-image | cat
```

The pole will happen, and then you will get the same sort of output that you mentioned above.

It is likely that the way that you are calling the `docker` CLI is not allocating the pseudo-tty, causing it to not stream the progress information to standard out.

Try calling the executable with a pseudo-tty allocated to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I did not have much idea about this concept. Now I am familiar. However, I have tried to find enabling tty in nodejs spwan/child process but no luck. It would be really great if you can tell me the ways of doing it.